# Button btn1_click is not executing

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

`btn1_click` is not functioning.  There are no errors or warnings in Visual Studio 2017.  There has to be something simple I am not doing.  I am certain that my api site is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>weatherjson</title>
    <style>
      body {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        right: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function btn1_click() {
        fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=40.79&lon=-81.347&exclude=minutely&appid=94d45728ae0f1341c6c5b0527162f90d').then(response => response.json()).then((obj) => {
          TextArea1.value = obj;
        });
      }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="get json" onclick="btn1_click()" />
    <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="200" cols="200"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you articulated what you are trying to accomplish here. When I ran your code in JSFiddle, it worked fine. You're sending the entire returned JSON to TextArea1. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your button, but i think you want to show the data in the text area so the way to do that you have to write which properties you need to show , this is how it should looks like

```js
function btn1_click() {
  fetch(
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=40.79&lon=-81.347&exclude=minutely&appid=94d45728ae0f1341c6c5b0527162f90d"
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((obj) => {
      TextArea1.value = `${obj.lat} ${obj.lon} ${obj.timezone} ${obj.current.dt}`;
    });
}
```

```css
 body {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     bottom: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     left: 0px;
     right: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: green;
 }
```

```html
 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="get json" onclick="btn1_click()" />
 <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="200" cols="200"></textarea>
```

To see which properties are available **console.log(obj)**

Comment: It works in JSFiddle but not in Visual Studio 2017.